# Identifying whether a condition given another condition for a given participant in a given lesson exists in a dataset

Tags: python, json, extract

I have a JSON file with data, and I am looking to see if a participant has completed a lesson by looking to see if an object called targetTitle has "Exit" where object pTitle has all the following text elements: "hard", "easy", "medium", "CD", "CH", "WU" for a given lesson.

Currently, the code cannot differentiate between the two following things:

#1: targetTitle has "Exit" and pTitle has all 6 text elements for a given lesson and participant at least once.

#2: targetTitle has "Exit" and pTitle has **one** of the 6 text element for a given lesson and participant at least once.

Here is example data:

```
[
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 CH",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 CD",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 WU",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 easy",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 medium",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 hard",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleNoEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 hard",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleNoEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson6 medium",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 CH",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 CD",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 WU",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 easy",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 medium",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        },
        {
            "Participant": "mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com",
            "Answer Details": {
                "pTitle": "Lesson21 hard",
                "targetTitle": "Exit"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Here is my current python script:

```
import csv
import json
import re

def check_participant(entry):
    participant = entry.get('Participant', 'Participant information missing')
    lessons_completed = {}

    # Check if 'Answer Details' key is present
    if 'Answer Details' in entry:
        answer_details = entry['Answer Details']

        # Get 'pTitle' and 'targetTitle' if present
        p_title = answer_details.get('pTitle', 'pTitle information missing')
        target_title = answer_details.get('targetTitle', 'targetTitle information missing')

        # Extract lesson number using regex
        lesson_number_match = re.search(r'(Lesson|L)(\d+)', p_title)
        if lesson_number_match:
            lesson_number = f"Lesson {lesson_number_match.group(2)}"
            # Check conditions
            completed = False
            if any(keyword in p_title for keyword in ['WU', 'CH', 'CD', 'easy', 'medium', 'hard']) and 'Exit' in target_title:
                completed = True
            lessons_completed[lesson_number] = 'Yes' if completed else 'No'

    return participant, lessons_completed

# Read data from JSON file
with open('example test.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Process data to create rows for each participant
participant_data = {}
for entry in data:
    participant, lessons_completed = check_participant(entry)
    if participant not in participant_data:
        participant_data[participant] = lessons_completed
    else:
        participant_data[participant].update(lessons_completed)

# Specify the CSV file path
csv_file_path = "Lesson Completed.csv"

# Write data to the CSV file
with open(csv_file_path, mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write header
    header = ['Participant'] + list(next(iter(participant_data.values())).keys())
    writer.writerow(header)

    # Write each row of data for each participant
    for participant, lessons in participant_data.items():
        row = [participant]
        for lesson, completed in lessons.items():
            row.append(completed)
        writer.writerow(row)

print(f"CSV file '{csv_file_path}' has been created successfully.")
```

Desired output example:

```
Participant,Lesson 6,Lesson 21
mailto:ExampleYesEmail@gmail.com,Yes,Yes
mailto:ExampleNoEmail@gmail.com,No
```

Comment: _"Exit" is present in all pTitle at least once for a participant in a given lesson and present at least once for a participant in a given lesson_ This sentence is confusing.  Firstly, what does "present in all pTitle" mean?  There is only one `pTitle` in the given sample file, so what you you mean by "all"?  Secondly, "at least once for a participant in a given lesson and present at least once for a participant in a given lesson" appears to say the same thing twice.

Comment: Perhaps if you gave an example including more records/rows that you have an input and what you are hoping to see as output.

Comment: Fixed the confusing sentence and expanded the example json data. Additionally, I provided a desired output example